# Round a column in a CSV file to a fixed number of decimal places

Tags: awk

I want to use awk to translate a CSV file into a new CSV file that has only a subset of the original columns. And I also need to round to 6 decimal places one of the columns which contains floating point numbers. Something like this:

```
gawk -F "," '
{
 label=$1;
 value=$2; # how do I round this to 6 decimal places?
 print ","label","value","
}' ./in.csv >> ./out.csv
```

I've looked a printf formatting but I don't know how to apply this to only certain columns.

How do I round a column in a CSV file to a fixed number of decimal places?

Comment: Can you please share your input file and expected output. If requirement is only to format 2nd column upto 6th decimal place. use below 

awk 'printf("%s,%-6s\n",$1,$2}' file.txt

Answer (score 2):

This should explain the both cases:

```
kent$  awk 'BEGIN{printf "%-6f, %-6f\n", 1/3, 5}'      
0.333333, 5.000000
```